# Symfony form: The selected choice is invalid

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, symfony-forms

My symfony app have this **entity**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

class Lead
{
    private ?string $zipCode;
    private ?string $city;

    public function getZipCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->zipCode;
    }

    public function setZipCode(string $zipCode): self
    {
        $this->zipCode = $zipCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(string $city): self
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And the Form **LeadType** is :

```
$builder->add('zipCode', TextType::class, [
        'attr' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Ex : 44000',
            'onchange' => 'cityChoices(this.value)',
        ]
    ])
    ->add('city', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => [],
        'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
        'choice_attr' => function () {return ['style' => 'color: #010101;'];},
    ]);
```

When the user enters a zip code, the **javascript** function *cityChoices()* add the select options using an external api like:

[image]

My problem is in the controller that the form is invalid. Because the user has selected a city that was not offered in the choices of **LeadType** (*'choices' => []*).

Here is the error:

```
0 => Symfony\Component\Form\FormError {#3703 ▼
          #messageTemplate: "The selected choice is invalid."
          #messageParameters: array:1 [▼
            "{{ value }}" => "Bar-le-Duc"
          ]
```

How to make the choice valid?

Comment: you modify the form using [Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) and then you reload and redraw the entire form.

Comment: @mbyou, since you configured `'choices' => [],` symfony-validation consider everything other than `[]` as invalid. So after you submit a form with ``Bar-le-Duc"` which is not in `[]` → validation fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completly @craight

I add to the form :

```
->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent$event){
   $form = $event->getForm();
   $city = $event->getData()['city'];
   if($city){
       $form->add('city', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => [$city => $city]]);
   }
})
```

When pre submit, I update choices and I put only the user select `'choices' => ['Bar-le-Duc' => 'Bar-le-Duc'],`

The form becomes valid in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, when using `EntityType` with an entity that was available before, but is not anymore (for example, soft deleted, or expired), is to use a custom data transformer to filter the posted results before validation.

See [How to Use Data Transformers @ Symfony Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html).

In the (non functional) example below, a custom data tranformer for the `EntityType` (or `ChoiceType`) removes invalid values according to the database query results for the given custom filter:

```php
<?php

/**
 * Transformer for collection of CustomerType objects.
 *
 * @implements DataTransformerInterface<Collection<array-key,string>,Collection<array-key,string>>
 */
class EntityCollectionTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    protected ?Builder $queryBuilder = null;

    /**
     * The valid DeliveryPackOption::id for the current context.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected ?array $validIds = null;

    /**
     * Constructor, injects the repository.
     */
    public function __construct(
        protected readonly EntityRepository $repository
    ) {
    }

    /**
     * Get the query builder, to apply custom filters.
     */
    public function getQueryBuilder(): Builder
    {
        // Reset the query builder
        $this->queryBuilder = $this->repository->getQueryBuilder();

        // Reset the valid ids
        $this->validIds = null;

        return $this->queryBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Get the valid DeliveryPackOption Ids for the current context.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getValidIds(): array
    {
        if (null !== $this->validIds) {
            return $this->validIds;
        }

        if (null === $this->queryBuilder) {
            $message = sprintf('You must call getQueryBuilder() before calling using %s.', self::class);
            throw new \LogicException($message);
        }

        /** @var Collection<array-key,Entity> */
        $results = $this->queryBuilder->getQuery()->execute();

        // Get the valid ids from the database
        $this->validIds = array_map(
            fn (Entity $option): string => $option->getId(),
            $results->toArray(),
        );

        return $this->validIds;
    }

    /**
     * Check that the given Entity::id are available as choices for the current context.
     *
     * Prevent "invalid" choices to be submitted.
     *
     * @param Collection<array-key,string>|null $value
     *
     * @return Collection<array-key,string>
     */
    #[\Override]
    public function transform(mixed $value): Collection
    {
        if (!$value instanceof Collection || 0 === $value->count()) {
            return new ArrayCollection();
        }

        return new ArrayCollection(array_filter(
            $value->toArray(),
            fn (string $id): bool => in_array($id, $this->getValidIds(), true)
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Transform a Entity:id array to its corresponding ArrayCollection of Document.
     *
     * @param Collection<array-key,string>|null $value
     *
     * @return Collection<array-key,string>|null
     */
    #[\Override]
    public function reverseTransform(mixed $value): ?Collection
    {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

And in the form, get the transformer service, and set the custom query filter:

```php
<?php

class FormType extends AbstractType {
    protected ?EntityTransformer $entityTransformer = null;

    /**
     * Set the DeliveryPackOptionReferenceCollectionTransformer service, used for dependency injection.
     */
    #[Required]
    public function setEntityTransformer(
        EntityTransformer $entityTransformer
    ): void {
        $this->entityTransformer = $entityTransformer;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        if (!$this->entityTransformer instanceof EntityTransformer) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('EntityTransformer service is not set.');
        }

        // Prepare the Entity collection filtering transformer query builder
        $qb = $this->entityTransformer->getQueryBuilder();
        $qb->andWhere('deleted = :false');
           ->setParameter('false', false);

        $builder
            ->add('city', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Entity::class,
            ])
        ;

        $builder->get('delivery.deliveryPackOptions')
            ->addModelTransformer($this->entityTransformer);
    }

}
```